# Configure domain to send traffic to a specific port

Tags: networking, dns

I'm planning on buying two domains.
Let's say they are `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.
I will point them at two custom servers that I have on my computer, both of them having an HTML "browsable" endpoint.
I want to know if it's possible to point `domain1.com` to `mycomputer:12345` and `domain2.com` to `mycomputer:9876`, so when you open, for example, `domain2.com` with your browser, it redirects the traffic to `mycomputer:9876`, without writing explicitly `domain2.com:9876`.
I've been searching for information about DNS records and reverse proxies, but I'm unable to figure out a way to achieve this, or something close to it.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a reverse proxy server eg. nginx.

All you need to do is configure each domain to to the appropriate server and port in the nginx config.

Just for your information - At DNS level you can't mention ports, as DNS servers doesn't carry port information.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're saying that by pointing both domains to my ip, (port 80 by default in a web browser), where a nginx server resides configured in some way, I'm able to discern from which domain the traffic came and redirect it to a given port accordingly?

Comment: Very much appreciated!!